# Macro VBA Replace command - misbehaviour

Tags: excel, vba, replace

There is some issue with this code that is used to change specific names in a specified sheet. When I ran this during testing phase, it worked fine. But when I actually wanted to use it, it for some reason changed names in all sheets in the workbook. What is wrong with the code?

```
Dim fndList As Variant
Dim rplcList As Variant
Dim x As Long

fndList = Array("Travel Total", "Utilities Total", "BFS_Total", "CPS_Total", "DMRT_Total", "Insurance Total")
rplcList = Array("Travel", "Utilities", "BFS", "CPS", "DMRT", "Insurance")

For x = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Neg GC% Gap (val)").Cells.Replace What:=fndList(x), Replacement:=rplcList(x), LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Next x
```

Comment: Doesn't appear to be anything in that code which would affect other sheets.

Comment: If you hit Ctrl+F to open the Find/Replace dialog, what is the "Within" option set to? "Sheet", or "Workbook"?

Comment: FWIW that code is using Excel's `Excel.Range.Replace` function, not VBA's `VBA.Strings.Replace` function as the title suggests. Always provide all optional arguments to `Range.Find` & `Range.Replace`.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comment of your question Excel keep the last used Find&Replace options.
This is a trick to run before your replace:

```
Set trick = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Neg GC% Gap (val)").Range("A1:A1").Find("trick", LookIn:=xlValues)
```

You can run this short code before looping through your list.